# Limits - Differential Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, golden-ratio

What I really want to ask is simple, and something which deals with the concept of limits and not really problem solving. So my question is

> *Do limits exist only for functions? Or do they exist for other mathematical expressions like fractions, or some special types of series?*

For example, if we have the Fibonacci sequence of numbers $(1,1,2,3,5,8,\dotsc)$, can we define a limit as the following
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}} = \text{Golden Ratio}= 1.618033\dots
$$
because here we don't have any function and still I am applying a limit to it. So is that possible for mathematical expressions other than functions?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Doesn't help to notice that the second term has negative base, so function is undefined over the reals not including the naturals.

Comment: Sequences are functions. In fact the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence has closed form $f_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n- \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla But then your comment isn't very obvious.  Whether or not your $f_n$ is $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is not immediately clear, nor is it very clear the limit of ratios be $\phi$.

Comment: **Counterexample:** Limits do not exist for you because you are *Limit-less*. Badabim!

Comment: Now, not talking shit: I guess you're confusing something: What is the meaning of "having a function"? Having a function for the Fibonacci numbers in terms of recurrence is *"having a function"*, the rule is just a little bit different of having - for example - $f(x)=\log x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, limits are defined on [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). More generally, limits are defined in [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology#A_topology_on_a_set) (every metric space is a topological space, but the converse is not true).

A *metric space* is a set $X$ along with a *distance function* $d$ that assigns a distance (a nonnegative real number) $d(x,y)$ between any two points $x,y$. A limit tries to captures the idea of a sequence of points $(x_n)_n$ approaching a particular point $x$, written $x_n \rightarrow x$. The notion of "approaching $x$" is [made rigorous through the distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition).

Limits of functions can be defined using sequences: We say that $f(x^\prime)\rightarrow y$ as $x^\prime \rightarrow x$ if given any sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, $f(x_n)\rightarrow y$. You may have seen a different (but equivalent) definition in your classes/books.

(I would learn about metric spaces before moving onto topological spaces)

Comment: however may limits don't exist, unless cauchyness of the sequence and completeness of the metric space is granted

Answer (score 0):

They exist in sequences, like the one you have shown (one of my favorite actually).

Limits can always be applied to any scenario that has the [epsilon-delta definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) of a limit applicable.  e.g.

$$\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}-\phi\right|<\epsilon$$

where $a_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.  I leave it to readers to attempt to finish this limit verification.